# get all my lists with a certain column powershell

Tags: powershell

How can I find all lists in my site that has a column of 'marking' in powershell.
I have a large site so cannot go through manually looking so wanted to know if there was a way of doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code to check the column:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://sitecollectionurl"
foreach($list in $web.Lists)
{
    if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary")
    {
        if( $list.Fields.ContainsField("ddlTest") -eq $true)
        {                                       
            Write-Host "found" $list.title
        }
        else
        {
            #  Write-Host "not found"  
        }
    }
}
```