# Filter Document Libraries based on a column name

Tags: document-library, powershell, column

```
Get-SPWeb http://sharepoint/sites/training |
Select -ExpandProperty Lists |
Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "SPDocumentLibrary" } |
Select Title
```

I have this code which outputs all of the document libraries in my site. Some of these libraries contain the column 'mark' how can I filter out the document libraries that do not contain this column? Is there a `$_.ContentType`

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101707/get-all-my-lists-with-a-certain-column-powershell - which I see now was also posted by you :/

Comment: BTW, if all you need is the inverse of your question from yesterday, the "not equals" operator in PowerShell is "-ne". So take the script Aanchal already gave you and flip it to use "-ne"; or even just toggle the condition check to $false

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more "Where" statement - tested and working. :)

```
cls
Get-SPWeb https://contoso.com |
Select -ExpandProperty Lists |
Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "SPDocumentLibrary" } |
Where { $_.Fields.ContainsField("customFieldName") -eq $true } |
Select Title
```